# Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: 2010, web-services, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to deploy my web service to SharePoint 2010.  Everything builds fine in VS 2013, and other developers seem to be able to deploy with no issues.

I've deleted the solution and repulled it down from github.  I've removed the solution from SP to try to get a fresh deployment.  I've cleaned the solution.  I've deleted the bin folder.

The only error I get when I try to deploy it:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types.  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

I don't know what relevant information you guys might need to help me with this so I'll add things if you need more info.

Any sort of pointers or direction would be awesome.  Again, if you need any more info, I'll try to post it.

Thank you!!

Edit:  Based on the information found [here](https://soerennielsen.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/fixing-the-timer-service-when-everything-breaks-down/) I have the following dump:

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2016 @ 3:09:40 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   ;BLAH.Configurator.Data\bin\Debug LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache
>   Base = NULL LOG: AppName = vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe Calling
>   assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT
>   VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
>
> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2016 @ 3:09:40 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   ;BLAH.Configurator.Data\bin\Debug LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache
>   Base = NULL LOG: AppName = vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe Calling
>   assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT
>   VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.Data/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
>
> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2016 @ 3:09:42 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   packages\nspec.0.9.68\tools;BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests\packages\nspec.0.9.68\tools;BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests\bin\Debug
>   LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName =
>   vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT
>   VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
>
> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2016 @ 3:09:42 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   packages\nspec.0.9.68\tools;BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests\packages\nspec.0.9.68\tools;BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests\bin\Debug
>   LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName =
>   vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT
>   VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/packages/nspec.0.9.68/tools/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
>
> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2016 @ 3:09:43 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   ;BLAH.Configurator.WebService\bin\Debug LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG:
>   Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT
>   VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
>
> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2016 @ 3:09:43 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   ;BLAH.Configurator.WebService\bin\Debug LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG:
>   Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe
>   Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT
>   VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.discoveryengine.x86.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/BLAH.Configurator.WebService/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/Extensions/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/BLAH/BLAH.Configurator/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

I'm way out of my territory here and have no idea how to read this and what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of an answer, but no explanation as to what caused the problem.  I reinstalled update 5 for VS2013.  Restarted and everything started working.